# Subtracting two dates of same dataset in R

Tags: r

I would like to create an X variable, which would be the subtraction between 03/07/2021, which is in my `date2`, and the day which is in my `date1`, ie 28/06/2021. Therefore, the result is 5.

```
 df <- structure(
      list(date1 = c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                     "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
           date2 = c("2021-04-02","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-06-30","2021-07-01","2021-07-02","2021-07-03")),
      class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
X <- as.Date(df$date2) - as.Date(df$date1)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! But wouldn't the answer have to be 5? because there are 5 days of difference between these two dates.

Comment: Right, it is. In my answer the X contains the differences between the dates for all the observations (i.e., rows) in the data frame. Try this: `df$delta <- as.Date(df$date2) - as.Date(df$date1)` and inspect the new delta variable in your data frame. If you're solely interested in the difference between dates in just the 9th observation, you can write `as.Date(df$date2[9]) - as.Date(df$date1[9])`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you after a column of the differences between all the dates?

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df |>
  mutate(across(.cols = everything(), as.Date), x = (date2 - date1))
```

Changing the columns first to dates would make it easier to plot later, but you can keep them as characters:

```
df <- df |>
  mutate(x = as.Date(date2) - as.Date(date1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the difftime function since it gives control over the units which will be outputted. Further you should convert your data type from chr to date seperatly since there could be a typo which would lead to an error.

```
df$date1 = as.Date(df$date1)
df$date2 = as.Date(df$date2)
(X = difftime(df$date1,df$date2,units = "days")) #Extra bracket for console output
```

Output:

Time differences in days

[1] 87 86 81 80 79 -2 -3 -4 -5